# How to switch between css with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have two forms which are places inside a ul and `<li id=visa class=active>` can be used to show one form and `<li id=mastercard class=active>` can be used to show the other form at a time.But the jquery I have below is made in such a way that its an onclick function.When I click on a link,visa,visa class is active,whn i click on mastercard,mastercard is active.But instead of onclick function I need a jquery which can make the class active on input given in a card_number field.When I input a number starting with 4,`<li id=visa class=active>` must be done,and when I insert number starting with 5 `<li id=mastercard class=active>` must take place.

Given below is my html

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>



    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // Switch cards
        jQuery('.switchCard').click(function(e){
            var newCard = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery('.cards li.active').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
                jQuery(newCard).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    jQuery(newCard).addClass('active');
                });
            });
        });
    });


    </script>


     <script src="main.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

       <section class="card-select">
            <h2>Select Payment Type</h2>
            <div class="wrap">
                <a href="#visa" class="switchCard">
                    <img src="visa.png">
                </a>

                <a href="#mastercard" class="switchCard">
                    <img src="mastercard.png">

            </div>
        </section>






    <ul class="cards">


    <li id="visa" class="active">
    <section class="credit-card visa gr-visa">
            <div class="logo">visa</div>
            <form>
                <h2>Payment Details</h2>

                <ul class="inputs">
                    <li>
                        <label>Card Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cardnumber" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" class="full gr-input" required />
                    </li>
              <li>
                <label>Name on card</label>
                <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                    <li class="expire last">
                        <label>Expiration</label>

                    <div class="dropdown">
          <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
         <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
         <option value="7">Jul</option>
         <option value="8">Aug</option>
         <option value="9">Sep</option>
         <option value="10">Oct</option>
         <option value="11">Nov</option>
         <option value="12">Dec</option>

          </select>
        </div>          

                <div class="dropdown">
          <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
            <option value="">Year</option>
               <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
         <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
         <option value="2019">2019</option>
         <option value="2020">2020</option>
         <option value="2021">2021</option>
         <option value="2022">2022</option>
         <option value="2023">2023</option>
         <option value="2024">2024</option>
          </select>
        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cvc-code last">
                        <label>CVV Code</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                    </li>
                  <input type="post" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButton"/>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </ul>
            </form>
            <div class="watermark">visa</div>
        </section>
    </li>
    <li id="mastercard">
    <section class="credit-card mastercard gr-mastercard">
            <div class="logo"><div></div><div></div></div>

            <form>
                <h2>Payment Details</h2>

                <ul class="inputs">
                    <li>
                        <label>Card Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="card_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" class="full gr-input" required />
                    </li>
              <li>
                <label>Name on card</label>
                <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                    <li class="expire last">
                        <label>Expiration</label>

                    <div class="dropdown">
          <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
         <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
         <option value="7">Jul</option>
         <option value="8">Aug</option>
         <option value="9">Sep</option>
         <option value="10">Oct</option>
         <option value="11">Nov</option>
         <option value="12">Dec</option>

          </select>
        </div>          

                <div class="dropdown">
          <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
            <option value="">Year</option>
               <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
         <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
         <option value="2019">2019</option>
         <option value="2020">2020</option>
         <option value="2021">2021</option>
         <option value="2022">2022</option>
         <option value="2023">2023</option>
         <option value="2024">2024</option>
          </select>
        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cvc-code last">
                        <label>CVV Code</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                    </li>
                <input type="post" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButtonM"/>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </ul>
            </form>
            <div class="watermark"><div></div><div></div></div>
        </section>

    </li>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The css is

```
/* === Basic reset === */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; box-sizing:border-box; }
a>img { border: none; }
header, footer, article, section, nav, aside { display: block; }

/* === General === */
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background:#ddd;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
/* === Credit Card === */
.credit-card {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:93.75%;   /* This is 300px on 320px wide screen */
    max-width:500px;    /* Just to make sure that it doesnt get crazy on bg screens */
    min-width:300px;    /* And make sure that it contains at least some size */
    margin:30px auto;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:6px;
    z-index:1;
}

.credit-card .inputs {
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:30px;

}

.credit-card .inputs li {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}


.credit-card .inputs li.last {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire {
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input{
    float:left;
    width:35%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input.month{
    width:30%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code {
    float:right;
    width:20%;


}
.creditcatd .inputs ul.cvc-code{
display: inline;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code input {
    width:70%;
}

.credit-card .watermark {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}

.credit-card form {
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.credit-card .logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* === Visa === */
.visa {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.visa h2 {
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(17,121,173,0.8);
}

.visa .logo {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    font-size:2em;
    font-style:italic;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(17,123,173,0.9);
}

.visa .logo:after {
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.visa .watermark {
    bottom:-100px;
    left:-50px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
    font-size:20em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
/* === Mastercard === */
.mastercard {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.mastercard h2 {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #2D4DAA;
}

.mastercard label {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mastercard input {
    border:1px solid rgba(39,70,157,0.8);
}

.mastercard .logo div {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.8);
}

.mastercard .logo div:first-child 
{
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.8);
    margin-right:-10px;
}

.mastercard .watermark {
    bottom:-130px;
    left:15%;
}

.mastercard .watermark div {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.1);
}

.mastercard .watermark div:first-child {
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.1);
    margin-right:-60px;
}
/* === Forms === */
label {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(17,123,173,0.6);
}

input {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 8px;
    color:#999;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px  1px 1px #fff;
    border:1px solid rgba(16,103,133,0.6);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:3px;
}

input.full {
    width:100%;
}


/* === Gradients === */
.gr-visa {
    background: #1db1cf; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%, #1078ab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1db1cf), color-stop(100%,#1078ab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1db1cf', endColorstr='#1078ab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gr-mastercard {
    background: #4d86ce; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%, #2d4daa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4d86ce), color-stop(100%,#2d4daa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d86ce', endColorstr='#2d4daa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gr-input {
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%, #d9d9d9 38%, #e5e5e5 82%, #e7e7e7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d3d3d3), color-stop(38%,#d9d9d9), color-stop(82%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#e7e7e7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#e7e7e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}








.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white #f7f7f7 #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 9px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px dashed;
  border-color: #888 transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:before {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown:after {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 130%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 10px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #62717a;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  /* Fallback for IE 8 */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  /* "transparent" doesn't work with Opera */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  color: #394349;
  outline: 2px solid #49aff2;
  outline: 2px solid -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-select > option {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fix for IE 8 putting the arrows behind the select element. */
.lt-ie9 .dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select {
  z-index: -1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Dirty fix for Firefox adding padding where it shouldn't. */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .dropdown-select {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
}
.fsSubmitButton
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #57d6c7;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
.fsSubmitButtonM
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #3dbdae;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}


/* === Card Selection === */
.card-select {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.card-select h2 {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#555;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.card-select .wrap {
    width:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #A0A0A0;
    background:rgba(176,176,176,0.4);
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card-select a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.card-select a img {
    width:15%;
}
```

the below css deals with the hiding and showing of the cards

```
/* === Cards === */
.cards {list-style:none;}
.cards>li {display:none;}
.cards>li.active {display:block;}
```

The jquery code which is used to switch the class using onclick is

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // Switch cards
        jQuery('.switchCard').click(function(e){
            var newCard = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery('.cards li.active').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
                jQuery(newCard).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    jQuery(newCard).addClass('active');
                });
            });
        });
    })

;
```

I dont know how can I modify the above code,so that I can change the class when i enter a numbers starting with so and so in the card number field

Im sorry for the long code description,but order to get a clear view,I have given this fully

js fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ check might help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/ is the jsfiddle

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/LJ9DV/ it maybe help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="cardnumber"]').on('keyup',function(){
   var cc_num = $('input[name="cardnumber"]').val();
   if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='4'){
    $("#visa").addClass("active");
    $("#mastercard").removeClass("active");
   }else if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='5'){
    $("#mastercard").addClass("active");
    $("#visa").removeClass("active");
   }
});
});
```

Comment: sir this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/3/ and i updated the code with this.But it doesnt seeems working.I think the code is correct,but what is going wrong?

Comment: This one is wokring! There is a small mistake that instead of "#...",'#...' so as to add or remove class to the ul elements.Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try using change event of text box where ull enter the numbers

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert("Get the value and validate");
//if textbox val == 4 then master else visa
});
```